# How to get the string between two dots in bash?

Tags: git, bash, substring

I have several git-Repos in such format:

```
product.module1.git
product.module2.git
...
```

Now I just want to iterate over the list to get just

```
module1
module2
```

How can I achieve this? I've already tried ls in combination with grep, but I'm not able to remove the first and last string parts.

Comment: You don't have to write "Thanks" or "Regards", or sign with your name, since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `grep` supports the `-P` option:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=[.])\w+(?=[.])' file
module1
module2
```

`(?<=[.])` is a look behind.  It matches, in this case, just after a period.

`\w+` matches any number of word characters.

`(?=[.])` is a look ahead.  It matches, in this case, just before a period.

Comment: Very useful and very fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A `cut` will do the job:

```
cut -d . -f2 file
module1
module2
```

Or awk:

```
awk -F. '{print $2}' file
module1
module2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r line; do 
  if [[ "$line" =~ \.(.*)\. ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done < file
```

Output:

```
module1
module2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, using an array and `IFS` to tokenize is easy:

```
var="product.module1.git"
IFS="." tokens=( ${var} )
echo ${tokens[1]}
# this outputs module1
```